# Jquery .toggle() causing element to fade out on page load

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to create an effect where when you click on an element it's size increases and when it's clicked again it goes back to the original size. For some reason when I'm using JQuery's toggle method it is causing the element (in this example a div) to shrink when the page loads. Here's a link to a 
JSFiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/6HNkF/ and here's my JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mainImg').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#mainImg').animate({
                    width: '1000',
                    height: '1000'
                }, 500);
            },
            function(){
                $('#mainImg').animate({
                    width: '100',
                    height: '100'
                }, 500);
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: I see that you've accepted an answer, but I would recommend that you use the most up to date version of jQuery instead of using an old version just for this one feature. I've added a replacement for `toggle` that you can use if you really need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) as a click event was deprecated in 1.8. and finally removed in version 1.9.

**[.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)**

> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions" signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated. The former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used to restore the functionality.

[As you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/6HNkF/9/), it works with version 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

The `toggle` functionality is no longer available in jQuery 1.9+. What you're trying to accomplish can be done conveniently with CSS transitions and a class:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mainImg').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("wide");
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainImg{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#mainImg.wide{
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
}
```

You can find a demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/WCwXm/

As a general solution, you can reintroduce an alternative to the `toggle` method under a different name:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.alternate = function() {
    var args = arguments,
        currIndex = 0;
    function toggler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return args[(currIndex++) % args.length].apply(this);
    }
    return this.click(toggler);
};
})( jQuery );
```

You can find a demonstration for this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FLrUk/).

Comment: For some reason the toggleClass alternative is instantly adding the class when the document loads. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @TonyBarsotti You should add the `toggleClass` to a click handler if you want it to change on click.

Comment: Ah thanks I got it working now. Much more efficient and much less code than my original script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) that you're using has been removed in jQuery 1.9. You can include [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate), which adds in these older methods back into newer jQuery versions:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure why they got rid of it. It was a useful method.

Comment: Because it's naming was confusing and you could do it yourself with a simple flag check. there was really no need for that overload.

Comment: Thanks that seems like it does the trick! I'll try to find a solution that isn't deprecated though.

Comment: @gdoron: I do agree that the name was confusing, but why couldn't they just rename it to something like `toggleclick`?

Comment: For the same reason `toggleChange` doesn't exist, so I believe.